# outgoing mail for web app (multiple domains as sender)

Tags: email, web, g-suite, web-applications

I have a web app "myapp.com" that users can use to set up their own websites. 
Our application is written in php and should be able to do the following:

- send mails to our own users "from: me@myapp.com"
- send mails from our clients to their clients "from: our@clientsdomain.com"

We don't need to take care of incoming mails, just send out mails with the correct from and reply-to addresses.

We cannot make this work using Google Apps (limited to our own domain in the from-field) and we cannot make google apps or google apps domains for all our clients, so we are looking for another simple to manage and set up solution.

Does anyone have experience with this, please let me know!
Thanks

Comment: what MTA are you using, postfix/sendmail etc

Comment: we haven't settled on a solution yet, but we are looking for the easiest solution to maintain, as we only want mails to get out for all domains. We won't be handling incoming emails

Answer (score 1):

Where is your web app hosted?  Your hosting provider will probably have their own outgoing SMTP servers that you can relay out through.  If they don't and you're running on your own server, you can install an SMTP relay server (such as sendmail for Linux or the IIS SMTP engine for Windows) and send the mail out directly.  If you go the direct route, ensure you have proper reverse DNS in place (there's a bunch of things to consider if you send out from your own server, but reverse DNS is usually a show-stopper if it's not in place).

Comment: we are hosting our own server

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to get you clients to add/alter the SPF record for their domain to allow you to send mail on their behalf.